# Slow transfers on localhost

Tags: google-chrome, xampp, html5, internet-speed

On my page, I have a HTML5 video tag with one .mp4 source. I've noticed that even though it's loading from the same physical machine, transfer speed is about 300kb/s. Even when loaded correctly the file transfers at this slow rate.

Apache is correctly set up to transfer mp4 video and the file has had the MOOV atom adjusted.

I've tried connecting through both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` to rule out any dns/ipv6 slowdowns.

It sounds to me like something is throttling the download, would anyone have any knowledge as to where the bottleneck would be?

---

Software:

> XAMPP v3.2.1
>   Chrome 30.0.1599.101m
>   Windows 8

Hardware:

> Intel i3-2365m
>   8GB DDR3 RAM